# mTLS tunnel between HAProxy instances?

Tags: haproxy

I've read several client side examples which involve a client and one HAProxy server. However, I'm wondering if it is possible to do the following with HAProxy.

I would like to have two HAProxy instances, call one client and one server. The server will act as a hub to many HAProxy clients. I would like the client side's backend to present a client cert to the server sides front end as well as the server side front end present a 'server' cert to the client such that the 2 HAProxy instances establish a mTLS link between them.

Then on the client side I would like the front end to perform TCP pass thru from any clients (such as curl) which connect to it and I want that passed thru connection to go across this mTLS tunnel to the server which would have a backend config that forwards it to a server behind it.

Here's a diagram of what I am trying to describe. TIA!
[image]

Comment: Yes, HAProxy can do this... but what's the application?

Comment: Could you give an example config that would allow this?

Comment: Can you describe the application?